# How to read through multiple files in a folder searching for a word + python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm building a little program that reads every line in a log file and if it finds a match it prints that line. The problem is, I have about 20 different log files and they all in the same folder. Is there a way I can parse through every single log file in a folder and print out the line that matches the searched word? Below is an example of what I have so far, but it prints nothing. The script needs to be able to incorporate readlines() and split()

What I have below doesn't work, but this is what I would expect it to look like. Any advice welcome.

```
  def Preview(): 
    path = ('C:Users/kev/Desktop/test/*.log')
    files = glob.glob(path)
    files.readlines()
    for line in files:
        if "test_word" in line:
            print line

   Preview()
```

Comment: your indentation is off... and `line.readlines()` just reads the file out to the void... `line` becomes a file handle.

Comment: check further into this line `TextTime = dt.strptime(line.split()[3], '%H:%M:%S.%f')`, as `dt.strptime` is returning a `<type 'time.struct_time'>` which you compare to a `str` "string" type, which will always fail.

Answer (score 0):

This is how your code should look:

```
def Preview(): 
    path = ('C:Users/kev/Desktop/test/*.log')
    files = glob.glob(path)
    for f in files:
        f = open(f)
        f = f.readlines():
        for line in f:
            if "test_word" in line:
            print line
        f.close()

Preview()
```

Comment: There were a few syntax issues in your code that I corrected, but it still doesn't work. Got the following error

f = f.readlines()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: Totally oversaw opening of file :) Please try the edit.

Comment: thank you!! - I also found this article which seemed to do the trick. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110469/do-a-search-and-replace-across-all-files-in-a-folder-through-python)